# Can't compare value of a JSON key with a text value

Tags: postgresql, json

```
SELECT id, 
       body->>'process_code' as process_code, 
       body->'filePaths' as files 
FROM masters."PROCESS"
where body->'filePaths' @> '[{"access_type": "Public"}]' 
  or  body->'filePaths'  @> '[{"access_type": "Private"}]'
  or  body->'is_blocked' = '1'
```

Sample JSON input:

```
{
    "filePaths": [
        {
            "doc_type": "Policy",
            "file_name": "asa.pdf",
            "file_path": "uploads/asa-1548048215360.pdf",
            "access_type": "Public"
        },
        {
            "doc_type": "Procedure",
            "file_name": "asa.pdf",
            "file_path": "uploads/asa-1548048233311.pdf",
            "access_type": "Private"
        }
    ],
    "created_by": "rhlsoni",
    "is_blocked": "0",
    "updated_by": "rhlsoni",
    "process_code": "DAP1000",
    "process_owner": "10",
    "created_timestamp": 1548048252,
    "process_objective": "sdvsdvsds",
    "updated_timestamp": 1550569867,
    "process_narratives": "<p>vwefwewefwefw</p>",
    "process_description": "DAP1000",
    "applications_involved": [
        "55"
    ]
}
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code Is working .

```
SELECT id, body->>'process_code' 
as process_code , body->'filePaths' as files 
FROM masters."PROCESS"
where body ->> 'is_blocked' = '1'
AND (body->'filePaths' @> '[{"access_type": "Public"}]' 
or  body->'filePaths'  @> '[{"access_type": "Private"}]')
```